# Can I use 'different different' in a sentence?

Tags: grammaticality

Is this a correct statement? - "He asked me different different questions."

Comment: What are you trying to convey by repeating "different"?

Comment: No. On the face of it this is not grammatical.  I suppose if you intended to differentiate between one person’s idea of *different* and another’s you might get away with talking about a *different* different.

Comment: @Jim What rule of grammar is it contravening? 'Colorless green ideas sleep furiously' is far harder to make sense of, and probably best decreed 'unacceptable', but is perfectly grammatical. Putting the first 'different' in italics _would_ be a sensible visual aid, though.

Comment: If the desired effect is emphasis on "different," a comma should be spliced in such that it reads "He asked me different, different questions." This is a rhetorical device called "epizeuxis". @Kay Gee, tell us a bit more about the context.

Comment: We have no way of knowing whether it's a correct statement or not—we don't know who ‘he’, not whether the different questions he asked you were in fact different (or from what).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth- you are correct.  I jumped the gun on *ungrammatical*   this is a phrase that some of my Indian friends use and it just rubs me the wrong way. I’d like to eradicate it.

Comment: @Jim, Yes, you got the context right.

Comment: It is perfectly grammatical and also is meaningful in the correct context.  (This context would generally be something like:  A: He asked me some different questions.  B: You mean he asked about Project Q?  A: No, he asked me *different* different questions.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's acceptable without italics, and even with them it's a comical construction that wouldn't have a place anywhere comedy is inappropriate. I can imagine it in a discourse like the following:

"I requested that he ask me different questions, but when he did, I didn't like those, so I requested that he ask me *different* different questions."

Comment: a different question = a question that's different from the one already asked. It's not easy to understand 'different' different question.

Answer (score 1):

The straight and simple answer is "no".

"different different questions" sounds like the literal, word-for-word translation from a language of the Indian sub-continent. Let's not forget that each and (almost) every language has different word orders (syntax), rules of grammar, styles, idioms, etc. based on its origin, which when translated should be made acceptable in the target-language.

What sounds like "He asked me different different questions." in your language, can only be translated as "He asked me different (or various) questions."

Comment: My pleasure! Welcome to EL & U!

Answer (score 0):

It is an unusual sentence but it makes sense in certain circumstances. I understand that he asked you a set of questions that were different (from each other), but you did not like them so requested a different set.

Comment: Yes, this is the scenario in which we use two 'different's in my mother tongue. So, when we try to express in English lot of people from our place use two 'different's in English too. Peril of word-by-word translation I thought.

Comment: You might be able to get the same meaning by using "He asked me still different questions". I'd be interested to know what other people think about this construction (whether it conveys the meaning you intend).

Answer (score 0):

There is a productive feature of English, a reduplication commonly understood to mark attestation to the genuineness / prototypicality of an article ('coffee coffee'; 'the Woman woman' ['Sherlock']). This could be the usage here:

> "I thought I'd prepared well, but the head of the interview panel
>   really worked me over with some questions I hadn't expected."
>
> "Well, they're always thinking up testing new ways to angle the
>   questions."
>
> "He asked me *different* different questions." (ie totally different)

Answer (score 0):

Well, we've got the definitive answer:  no, yes, *sometimes*.

The problem is really with the question, "Can I use....?"  This is often phrased as "Is this correct?" or "Is this grammatical?"

There are some constructs which violate the syntactical rules of the language in such a way that no native speaker would recognize them as valid:

> She are was to-ing go the park.

English does not use "are" as an auxiliary with "was"; English does not form a gerund by appending -ing to the word "to," and so on.  Sometimes the words fit the required template, but the meaning is too absurd to admit of correctness, as in dangling constructions:

> The keys having been found, the car was driven to the park.

Sometimes the propriety is based on "standard English" that vernaculars violate easily and understandably:

> She and I be going to the park.

Other times, the template is satisfied but the word choice is not idiomatic.  For instance "argue" takes a prepositional phrase to indicate the topic ("about something") or the opponent ("with someone") but not

> She argued upon him.

The example "different different questions" really doesn't fit in any of these categories.  English allows Adjective-Adjective-Noun phrases:

> big red car

English allows Adjective-Same adjective-noun to indicate intensity:

> mad mad world

The trouble with "different different questions" is that it's an unusual locution that's ambiguous.  As commenters have pointed out, does it mean really, really different?  Or was the person expecting one element from a  set of dissimilar questions but got unexpected questions instead?